# Xcode - terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: ios, xcode

I will not ask the question about what causes this error. It has been replied multiple times.
When I get this error

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

These are the last lines in the console, Xcode doesn't give me more informations. No details, why ? Is this behavior normal ?

Comment: show your codes )

Comment: There can be many reasons which can lead to this. Add the whole issue log, screenshot. This could also happen if you've wired up a button to an IBAction that doesn't exist anymore (or has been renamed)